# Mysql : Can the balance ever get negative

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query:

```
Update xyz 
SET `bal`=`bal`-100 
WHERE `bal`>'100' 
AND user='pqr'
```

DB engine: InnoDB

Is it possible that the balance of the user ever gets below 0, I am thinking like if the user opens the page which runs the query simultaneously in two tabs. Do I need to do something to prevent the negative balance issue or is it automatically handled by the database.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't possible. Because `WHERE bal > 100` means you always set bal `>= 0`

Comment: Note the check is against a string, not a number. '20' is greater than '100'

Comment: Is this homework? I find it unusual that such code ended up in production

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Some frameworks actually write int values as string in some contexts. This might not be that unrealistic. This query is handwritten, though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not homework, but the simplified version of the actual query to highlight the issue. I just wanted to make sure that explicit locking/unlocking of the db/records is not required in this case.

Comment: Locking is irrelevant to *this* question. `UPDATE` is atomic. You *can* get negative results because you are doing an alphabetic comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this query the balance con not be zero:

```
 "Update xyz SET `bal`=`bal`-100 WHERE `bal`>100 AND user='pqr'"
```

Becuase it only selects entries, which have a balance >100. A number bigger than 100 - 100 can not be lower then zero.

I guess your column `bal` is a numberical field, it is better to remove th quotes arround the 100.

Answer (score 2):

Unless MySQL implicitly casts `'100'` to a number, this query *can* lead to a wrong result. The where statement compares against the *string* value `'100'`, not the integer 100. '20' is greater than `'100'` alphabetically, so it can pass the filter.

Answer (score 0):

bal will not be less than 0. It will always be greater than zero. It is actually quite clear from your code where 'bal' > 100

```
Update xyz 
SET `bal`=`bal`-100 
WHERE `bal`>'100' 
AND user='pqr'
```